How can I correctly use [FromQuery] (C# ASP.NET Core Web API) in the following code to call different methods
This is my first attempt at working with an ASP.NET Core Web API, so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is sensible. I'm trying to have one endpoint that can have additional optional parameters and depending on what those optional parameters are, call different methods.
In the code below, I tried checking if pageIndex, pageSize, fromIndex and result count are null to direct the code to the required method. However, all of those variables are 0 when I hit the end point. I then tried using nullable ints (int? pageIndex) but the methods I subsequently call can't use nullable ints. I can't use something like pageIndex != 0 because 0 might be a valid result. Is there a way to do this properly or should I create 3 different endpoints for the three methods (in the provided code snippet I know my return type is wrong, I pulled out only the relevant code from my actual method).
Code:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class QueryController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{queryId}")]
    public async Task<BaseResponse> GetProgressAndResults(string queryId, [FromQuery] int pageIndex, [FromQuery]int pageSize, [FromQuery]int fromIndex, [FromQuery]int resultCount)
    {
        if (pageIndex != null && pageSize != null)
        {
            var bob = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetResultsPaginatedAsync(queryId, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
        else if (fromIndex != null && resultCount != null)
        {
            var bob1 = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetResultsAsync(queryId, fromIndex, resultCount);
        }
        else
        {
            var bob2 = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetAllResultsAsync(queryId);
        }
    }
}


You could use .Value pass to the interface:
[HttpGet("{queryId}")]
public async Task<BaseResponse> GetProgressAndResults(string queryId, 
    [FromQuery] int? pageIndex = null,
    [FromQuery] int? pageSize = null,
    [FromQuery] int? fromIndex = null,
    [FromQuery] int? resultCount = null)
{
    if (pageIndex != null && pageSize != null)
    {
        var bob = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetResultsPaginatedAsync(queryId, pageIndex.Value, pageSize.Value);

    }
    else if (fromIndex != null && resultCount != null)
    {
        var bob1 = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetResultsAsync(queryId, fromIndex.Value, resultCount.Value);

    }
    else
    {
        var bob2 = await _ultinousKafkaClient.GetAllResultsAsync(queryId);

    }
}


Cheers, that worked thanks.
